# Decode pickle file in human-readable format in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import pickle

data_pkl = open("data.pkl", "rb")
d_c = data_pkl.read()
data_pkl.close()
print(d_c)
```

I am new to handling data structure. When I tried to read pickle data and result looks like below:

b'\x80\x03}q\x00(X\x05\x00\x00\x00Phoneq\x01}q\x02(cnumpy.core.multiarray\nscalar\nq\x03cnumpy\ndtype\nq\x04X\x02\x00\x00\x00i8q\x05K\x00K\x01\x87q\x06Rq\x07(K\x03X\x01\x00\x00\x00

......... long line

How can I convert this to human-readable format in python?

Comment: Your pickle is returning a bytes literal which means it has ascii characters \x, \x00, etc.
so you need to decode it try print(d_c.decode('utf-8'))

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `pickle` to read the file?

Comment: @Mntfr Pickle file format is not that straightforward. It is not enough to call `decode()`.

Comment: @Mntfr This is not a text format. And it is not encoded in UTF-8. So you cannot decode it like that. You need to use `pickle.loads`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a data is dumped, [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) produce a bytes string. This is what you have.

For instance:

```py
import pickle

data = {'text': 'value', 'list': [1, 2, 3]}

s = pickle.dumps(data)
print(s)
```

Produces the bytes string:

```py
b'\x80\x03}q\x00(X\x04\x00\x00\x00textq\x01X\x05\x00\x00'
b'\x00valueq\x02X\x04\x00\x00\x00listq\x03]q\x04(K\x01K'
b'\x02K\x03eu.'
```

*note*: I split the long line in 3 parts for readability.

Python defines several protocols, names `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL` and `DEFAULT_PROTOCOL`. So, If you change the protocol you can have a different result.

To read this bytes string, you need to use `pickle.load` (or `pickle.loads` to read from a bytes string).

For instance:

```py
import pprint

obj = pickle.loads(s)
pprint.pprint(obj)
```

You get:

```py
{'list': [1, 2, 3], 'text': 'value'}
```

Cool, but if your data contains instance of unknown type, you won’t be able to deserialize it.

Here is an example:

```py
import pickle
import pprint


class UnknownClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value


data = {'text': 'value',
        'list': [1, 2, 3],
        'u': UnknownClass(25)}

s = pickle.dumps(data)
print(s)

del UnknownClass

obj = pickle.loads(s)
```

The `del` statement is here to simulate an unknown type.

The result will be:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/stack.py", line 19, in <module>
    obj = pickle.loads(s)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'UnknownClass' on <module '__main__' from '/path/to/stack.py'>
```

For more info, the protocols are specified in the Python documentation.

Answer (score 2):

When google brought me to this question, the answer that I would have liked to have seen was to `import pickletools` and then use `pickletools.dis(s)` to explain what the various characters between the understandable substrings within pickle `s` were indicating.  This is only marginally human-readable, since it reads more like machine assembly language than python, but it still helps a human reader to peer behind the curtain and make some sense of the gobbledygook.

Of course, what we usually want isn't for *humans* to read serialized data, but for *computers* to read it and make good use of it.  When that's what you want, `pickle.load` or `pickle.loads` are the way to go.  Or if, for some reason, you want to serialize your data in a format that is both human-readable and machine-readable, you probably want some other serializer, like JSON, or you could set pickle to encode with the original pickle protocol 0, which was human-readable (but less efficient).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the Python documentation, in particular the [`pickle` module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). Your current code is importing `pickle`, but it's not actually using `pickle`, since you're just loading the file using `read()`. Using [`pickle.load()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.load) or another `pickle` method should do the trick.

For example:

```
d_c = pickle.load(data_pkl)
```

---

Editing to add the mandatory pickle warning from the docs:

> Warning: The pickle module is not secure against erroneous or maliciously
>   constructed data. Never unpickle data received from an untrusted or 
>   unauthenticated source.

(Unpickling an unknown file leaves you open to having arbitrary code executed on your computer, so be careful what you unpickle!)